# Special meshing in Fipy(3d meshing of a hollow cylinder)

Tags: python-2.7, mesh, fipy

I would like to mesh a cylindrical fracture as follows in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZKE.png)

The cells in the mesh have the hexahedral form with 6 faces and 8 nodes.This mesh will be used in  fipy to solve a diffusion equation.(radial flow)
could anyone help in answering my question regarding the mesh using gmsh code? since it is the only way being compatible with fipy.
I appreciate your help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You vaguely described what you are doing and asked if anyone would help. You didn't ask a question. Posting your code and a clearly framed question will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cylindrical symmetry, you can use [`CylindricalGrid1D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#fipy.meshes.factoryMeshes.CylindricalGrid1D) or [`CylindricalGrid2D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#fipy.meshes.factoryMeshes.CylindricalGrid2D) to generate your mesh. Offset the mesh to create the hole in the middle, e.g.:

```py
mesh = CylindricalGrid2D(dr, dz, Lr, Lz) + [[r0], [0]]
```

If your problem is not cylindrically symmetrical, then as @RanjeethMahankali commented, please show us what you've tried to do.

Comment: Mr @jeguyer , my problem here is **3D** **cylindrical** **symmetry**, so I need the three components of the vertex coords (x,y,z); With cylindricalGrid2D I have only x,y

Comment: At the beginning i was simulating the flow in a Grid3D (coupling fipy with a discrete element software called PFC3D, to take into account the particles while solving the diffusion equation of the flow :
`self.mesh = fipy.Grid3D(nx=10, ny=20, nz=10, dx=0.01, dy=0.01, dz=0.01)`
Now I want to move to a 3D radial flow...

Comment: Is it possible to have a translation of  the cylindricalGrid2D in z direction to have a 3D problem? Really I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. `CylindricalGrid2D` is defined in r and z, with cylindrical symmetry about r=0.

Comment: Mr Guyer, I think such type of mesh can't be performed via fipy mesh builder.the issue is that I need three components for the nodes (x, y, z) to build my mesh in my code (Itasca PFC3D).CFD simulations can be performed only on 3D problems.CylindricalGrid2D will give me only 2 components.I post a new question here [stackoverflow.com/questions/64818780/problem-in-loading-msh-file-in-fipy-via-gmsh3d] because I got some problems by importing my mesh from Gmsh.I appreciate your help.

Comment: In that case, your problem is not cylindrically *symmetrical*, even if it might end up being close.